# Connecting Mac to Adafruit Feather 32u4 Bluefruit LE over serial

Tags: serial, bluetooth

The Adafruit board connects fine over USB serial, and fine over Bluetooth to a mobile app, but it will not connect to a Mac serial monitor over Bluetooth.

Is there any way to use the Adafruit's Bluetooth chip as a pass-through, to allow serial communication over Bluetooth from the Mac to the board itself?

Comment: Have you checked google for: "Mac bluetooth as COM port"? A lot of interesting articles can be found.

Comment: @Sakar did u ever figure this out?